# Write an optionally executable (Lazy) function for Pandas columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a script with optionally "callable" columns.

Basic gist :

We have a base DataFrame with about 25 columns.  Average length ~ 3000 rows.
There are multiple additional attributes that may be added on call - up to 80 additional calculations are possible.

However, only if some calculations are successful with multiple branching (to be selected by user) do we go in for subsequent additions.

Question:
I would like to define all these additional columns here as functions for lazy execution i.e., executed only upon demand instead of pre-computing all these 80 columns and adding to the DataFrame.

For the user, it would still deliver a single result.

Would lambda functions be helpful?

```
df = df.assign(IsDate = lambda x:(x.dt < date(2021,11,1)))
```

Where the column ['IsDate'] should be lazy executed.
But, the below (is it equivalent) would not be lazy.

```
df['IsDate'] = x.dt < date(2021,11,1)
```

I am not sure if my question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

> Question: I would like to define all these additional columns here as functions for lazy execution i.e., executed only upon demand instead of pre-computing all these 80 columns and adding to the DataFrame.

Why don't you just create functions that add the desired columns to a DataFrame passed as an argument? And you only call those functions when a given condition is satisfied.

> ```
> df = df.assign(IsDate = lambda x:(x.dt < date(2021,11,1)))
>
> df['IsDate'] = x.dt < date(2021,11,1)
> ```

These two lines are equivalent. The first is not lazy executed, the column is created right away after the line is executed.

Don't you want something like

```
# if condition 1 is satisfied compute and add the 'IsDate' column to df
if cond_1: 
  df['IsDate'] = x.dt < date(2021,11,1)
  # if also condition 2 is satisfied, add 'new_column1'
  if cond_2:
  df['new_column1']  = .... 
     
if cond_3:
  df['new_column2']  = ....
```

Of course, you shouldn't nest too many if statements. I'm sure there are better ways to deal with the flow control depending on what you want exactly, which I didn't fully understand.

For more complex computations you can put the logic inside functions

```
def add_isdate(df):
   """ function that adds 'Isdate' to df. Mutates df in-place."""
   
   df['IsDate'] = x.dt < date(2021,11,1)

def add_related_cols(df):
   """ function that computes several similar calculations 
       and add them as columns to df. Mutates df in-place."""

   df['col1'] = (...)
   # do other computations 
   df['col2'] = (...)
   # (...)

df = pd.DataFrame(...)

# Add 'IsDate' to df (in-place) if cond_1 is met 
if cond_1:
  add_isdate(df)

# if cond_2 is met, do a bunch of computations and add them to df (in-place)
if cond_2:
  add_related_cols(df)
```

If you don't want the functions to add the columns in-place, you can create a copy of the DataFrame passed, and return another DataFrame with the additional columns

```
def add_column_not_inplace(df):
   """ computes new column(s). Returns a new 
       DataFrame with the additional column(s) """
   # make a copy of the DataFrame passed
   df_copy = df.copy()
   
   # compute and add the new columns
   df_copy['new_col'] = (...)
   # (...)
   
   # returns the copy of the original df with the new columns 
   return df_copy


df = pd.DataFrame(...)

# if cond_1 is met, add the column to df. 
# Assign the result to df1 as the functions doesn't act in-place
if cond_1:
  df1 = add_column_not_inplace(df)
```

Comment: @Kapil Does this answer your question?  If not, please clarify what you want.